# How to make an animation of a Rigify Rig that follows a circular path?

Tags: animation, bones, bezier-curves, rigify

[image]

The left hand rig highlighted in blue is what I want to be animated in a circular motion.

I added a circle curve (not mesh) around the hand I want animated. How do I make the hand follow the curve?

I have seen videos do this but they do it in Object Mode Animation not in Pose Mode. (e.g: Camera moves around a Circle Curve)

Answer (score 0):

In pose mode click on the bone, then add bone constraint...

[image]

follow path and choose as target your curve

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems that in my case, the whole root rig is being constrained in the curve despite selecting only the hand as shown here: https://imgur.com/l8gPGni

Comment: Can u pls provide blend file, so I can check it out?

Comment: Sure, here is the blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RnYmKFunJLWWlWcu2Fd3KJQL7OeXyjbQ/view?usp=sharing